# How to install webgen 0.5?

Tags: 12.04

I am having a problem installing webgen 0.5 in Ubuntu 12.04.

In particular, I have a website written in Markdown, and webgen 0.5 fails with:

```
Error while working on </index.en.html> with Webgen::ContentProcessor::Kramdown:
The needed library 'kramdown' is missing. You can install it via rubygems with 'gem  install kramdown'!
```

I try to install via:

```
-> sudo gem install kramdown
Successfully installed kramdown-0.13.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for kramdown-0.13.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for kramdown-0.13.7...
```

However, I still get the same error in webgen... (I tried installing in Ruby 1.8 gem, and Ruby 1.9 gem and I get the same error in both cases.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.  To answer my own question:

First off, one has to be careful to install **Ruby 1.8** gems.  First install Ruby 1.8 gems package:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
```

Next, to install kramdown, make sure to install **kramdown version 0.10.0** via:

```
sudo gem1.8 install kramdown -v 0.10.0
```

However, if you run `webgen` you will still get the error in the question.  The solution is to force ruby to use ruby gems on the path.  Before running `webgen` run:

```
export RUBYOPT=rubygems
```

If you did this but instead you installed the latest version of kramdown, then you get the following error (I paste it here so people can Google it):

```
Error while rendering </index.en.html>:
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Once the correct version of kramdown is installed, running webgen on markdown source works:

```
Starting webgen...
Updating tree...
...done in 0.0138 seconds
Writing changed nodes...
...done in 0.0011 seconds
Finished
```

It looks like there is a quantal package for ruby-kramdown.  So possibly, this workaround will not be necessary then.